# COLOR filter in CASE statements

Tags: mysql

My sample table looks as follows:

| Name | Sales | Tasks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Shawn | 10 | 0 |
| Martha | 20000 | 15 |
| Stewart | 0 | 5 |
| Angela | 0 | 0 |

I am trying to add a color filter to my case statements for better row identification

I want the first 3 rows to be in blue since they have some value in the 'sales' and 'tasks' field.
Whereas, for Angela, I want the row to be white in color.

```
CASE WHEN `Sales` IS NOT NULL AND `Tasks` IS NOT NULL
THEN '#B7DAF5' (light blue)
ELSE '#FFFFFF' (white)
END
```

It still shows every row as white.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`0` is not the same as `NULL`. Also, your condition is backwards, it will only make it light blue of ALL fields are not null; therefore, `Shawn` and `Stewart` would be white.

Simplify it by using a positive condition rather than negative.

```
CASE WHEN `Sales` = 0 AND `Tasks` = 0
THEN '#FFFFFF' -- white
ELSE '#B7DAF5' -- light blue
END
```

Answer (score 0):

In your sample table there are no NULLs in any of the rows, unless you are representing NULL with 0 (zero). Anyway, I think it would be necessary to know what client program you are using.

Answer (score 0):

The sample data you put contains `0` instead of `NULL` so you might want to check for is greater than 0 instead of `IS NOT NULL`.

```
select *,
CASE
    WHEN Sales > 0 or Tasks > 0 THEN "#B7DAF5"
    ELSE "#FFFFFF"
END as Color
from TableName
```